# How do I add an input field in a tr based on what option is selected Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am Trying to add an input field to a table based on what they select from my select list, but I just cant seem to get it to work.

I can remove the table row which is great but I can't add it I tried to check some resources but to no avail

here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('#tabSearch').hide();

  $('.addBtn').on('click',function(){
      var trObj = $(this).closest("tr");
      });

  $('.removeBtn').on('click',function(){
      var trObj = $(this).closest("tr");
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();        
  });
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9">
        <label for="searchByFilter"><strong>Select Search Terms</strong></label>
        <br />
        <div>
            <select id="searchByFilter" name="searchByFilter" style="width: 155px;">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">Name</option>
                <option value="2">Email</option>

            </select>
            <input type="button" style="margin-top: -5px;" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default addBtn" value="Add Filter" id="addBtn" name="addBtn" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />

        <div id="tabSearch" style="display: inline !important;">
            <table id="SearchFilters" style="width: 500px; display: inline-table; margin-bottom: 5px;" class='table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 100px;" class='tablecell'>Filter</td>
                        <td class='tablecell' style="width: 50px !important;">Action</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr id="trPersonName">
                    <td>
                        <input id="searchSPersonName" name="searchSPersonName" type="text" maxlength="12" size='15' style="width: 150px;" placeholder="Name" value='' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default removeBtn" style="float: none;">Remove Filter</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="trPersonEmail">
                    <td>
                        <input id="searchSEmail" name="searchSEmail" type="text" maxlength="10" size='11' style="width: 150px;" placeholder="Email" value='' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default removeBtn" style="float: none;">Remove Filter</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show your attempt to add the input?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more where you want to add the inputs? As far as I see the inputs are already in the table. Do you mean to hide/show them?

Comment: Sorry if my description is a bit off, what I want to happen when the user goes to the search tab (which is what im using it for)  only the select input will be shown where the user must select the filters they want to search on so if they select name, the name input field will apear in the table where they can add in the name or remove the filter with the remove button (which already works) if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

here there is an example to check if that's what you wanted to do

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //when you wante to add
        $('#add').on('click', function(){
            $('#tags').append(`<li class='added'>${$('#mySelect').val()}</li>`);
            $('#mySelect').val()
        }); 
   
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
<div>
    <h3>choose your tag</h3>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
      <option>Option 6</option>
      <option>Option 7</option>
      <option>Option 8</option>
    </select>
    <button id="add">add</button>
  </div>
  
  <h3>Tags click tag to remove it</h3>
  <ul id="tags"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work in my case but I found a solution ! thanks for your effort though